# Can't write ID3 tags using getID3 1.9.7

Tags: php, wordpress, id3, id3v2, getid3

I'm trying to take advantage of Wordpress' 3.6 support for getID3(), but I'm having trouble writing ID3 tags to my mp3s. Here is the code I'm using:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'getID3' ) ) {
    require(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/ID3/getid3.php' );
}

# I had to custom install the write library because WP doesn't include it by default, evidently
getid3_lib::IncludeDependency(TEMPLATEPATH.'/lib/getid3/write.php', __FILE__);

$testfile = "/Users/jplew/Sites/dev.example.com/content/uploads/mp3.mp3";

$tagwriter = new getid3_writetags;
$tagwriter->filename   = $testfile;
$tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v2.4');
$TagData['title'][]  = 'My Heart Will Go On';
$TagData['artist'][] = 'Celine Dion';
$TagData['genre'][]  = '90s Classics';

$tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;

if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failure';
}
```

I am consistently getting 'failure'. The path to the `getid3_writetags` function is fine. I know this because when I `print_r($tagwriter);`, it outputs all the arrays as specified. However the 'warnings' and 'errors' arrays are both empty.

Moreover, when I do the following it successfully returns all the correct tag information:

```
$data = $getid3->analyze( $testfile );
print_r($data)
```

I should also note that the `demo.write.php` included in the demos also fails when I run it. It gets as far as `starting to write tag(s)` then stops.

Any ideas? I'd post on the getid3.org forum but my IP is blacklisted. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress did not include the entire GetID3 library when they implemented it. They only used the files to get the most popular video and audio tags.